# Export data to microsoft excel from MS sql using C#

Tags: c#, excel

How can I use C# to export data to Microsoft Excel from MS-SQL?

Can anyone give me a sample of coding or related tutorial to connect to a database and click a button to export to Microsoft Excel?

Comment: I typed your exact question title into google and found lots of examples...

Comment: Asking the question II time WONT get you the answer unless you ask exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Did you know you can do this in SQL Server Management Studio by right-clicking the database and choosing Tasks->Export Data?

Answer (score -1):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;

namespace ExporExcel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=WINCTRL-KJ8RKFO;Initial Catalog=excel;Integrated Security=True");

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from Employee",con);
            sda.Fill(dt);
            ExportToExcel(dt);
        }

        public static void ExportToExcel(DataTable dtReport, string ExcelFilePath = null)
        {

                int ColumnsCount;

                if (dtReport == null || (ColumnsCount = dtReport.Columns.Count) == 0)

                    throw new Exception("ExportToExcel: Null or empty input table!\n");


                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application Excel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbooks.Add();


                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet Worksheet = Excel.ActiveSheet;

                object[] Header = new object[ColumnsCount];

                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
                    Header[i] = dtReport.Columns[i].ColumnName;

     Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range HeaderRange = Worksheet.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[1, 1]),
     (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[1, ColumnsCount]));

                int RowsCount = dtReport.Rows.Count;
                object[,] Cells = new object[RowsCount, ColumnsCount];

                for (int j = 0; j < RowsCount; j++)
                    for (int i = 0; i < ColumnsCount; i++)
                                Cells[j, i] = dtReport.Rows[j][i];

                Worksheet.get_Range((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[2, 1]), (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)(Worksheet.Cells[RowsCount + 1, ColumnsCount])).Value = Cells;
                Excel.Visible = true;
        }
      }
   }
```